# SimpleXmlElement + XPath. Индекс родительского узла

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые программисты. 
Есть xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

С помощью XPath я нахожу заголовок нужной книги

```
$xml->xpath("//title[text() = 'Harry Potter']);
```

И сталкиваюсь с проблемой поиска индекса для родительского узла`<book>`
Например: Для книги с заголовком `"Harry Potter"` индекс `1`.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне получить индекс книги. Заранее, огромное спасибо.

Comment: *Для книги с заголовком "Harry Potter" индекс 1* - Почему?

Comment: Потому что SimpleXmlElement представляет xml документ как массив и, соответственно, индексация идет с нуля.

Comment: именно в такой постановке вопроса, боюсь, что никак. Но можно же получить элемент book? ` //book[title[text() = 'Harry Potter']]`

Comment: Есть еще вот такой путь `count(//book[title[text() = 'Harry Potter']]/preceding-sibling::book)` но насколько я понимаю, порядок в файле, в поиске xpath  и в массивах полученных интерпретацией xml может быть разный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией simple_xml_load_string() или simple_xml_load_file(), и  эта проблема решится.

```
$string=<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
//print $xml->book[1]->title;
$cnt = count($xml);
for($i=0; $i<$cnt-1; $i++){
    $title = $xml->book[$i]->title;
    print "<br> index = $i title =$title";
    if($title == 'Harry Potter') $index = $i;
}
print("<br><br>index_required = $index");

print("<pre>"); print_r($xml); print("</pre>");
```

Результаты:

```
index = 0 title =Everyday Italian
index = 1 title =Harry Potter
index = 2 title =XQuery Kick Start

index_required = 1
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [book] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [category] => cooking
                        )

                    [title] => Everyday Italian
                    [author] => Giada De Laurentiis
                    [year] => 2005
                    [price] => 30.00
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [category] => children
                        )

                    [title] => Harry Potter
                    [author] => J K. Rowling
                    [year] => 2005
                    [price] => 29.99
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [category] => web
                        )

                    [title] => XQuery Kick Start
                    [author] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => James McGovern
                            [1] => Per Bothner
                            [2] => Kurt Cagle
                            [3] => James Linn
                            [4] => Vaidyanathan Nagarajan
                        )

                    [year] => 2003
                    [price] => 49.99
                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [category] => web
                        )

                    [title] => Learning XML
                    [author] => Erik T. Ray
                    [year] => 2003
                    [price] => 39.95
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо) Смотрел-смотрел инфу по SimpleXLM, но это просмотрел)

Comment: Тогда ещё simplexml_import_dom() гляньте